# Regex issues while parsing text file using Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Can someone assist me what I am doing wrong with parsing text file via Regex? Using Python to execute code. I have a response in text file below which I would like to parse and get **numvaluelist** value. Currently getting a TypeError.

**Error:**

```
lines = line_re.findall(data)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

**Text File (.txt) in String Format**

```
historic_list {
  id: "Text1(long) 11A"
  startdate: 345453
  numvaluelist: 0.123
  datelist: 345453
}
historic_list {
  id: "Text1(short) 11B"
  startdate: 345453
  numvaluelist: 0.456
  datelist: 345453
}
historic_list {
  id: "Text2(long) 11C"
  startdate: 345453
  numvaluelist: 1.789
  datelist: 345453
}
datelist: 345453
}
time_statistics {
  job_id: "123"
}
UrlPairList {
}
```

**Python Code**

```
f= open(".txt_file", "r")
data = f.readlines()
# print data

line_re = re.compile(r'\{[^\}]+\}')
value_re = re.compile(r"(\w+): ('[^']*'|\S+)")

results = []
lines = line_re.findall(data)
for line in lines:
    data_line = dict()
    values = re.findall(value_re, line)
    for (name, value) in values:
        if(value[-1] == '}'): value = value[:-1]  # to handle "foo}" without space
        if(value[:1] == "'"): value = value[1:-1]  # strip quotes
        data_line[name] = value
    results.append(data_line)

print type(results)

final_results = []
for i in results:
    for key, value in i.items():
        if key == 'numvaluelist':
            final_results.append(i['numvaluelist'])
print final_results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not your regex. `readlines` returns a list but `re.findall` takes a string or buffer.

What you want is:

```
data = f.read()
```

which returns the content of the file as a single string.